# where condition scenario in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, clause

i have requirement in where condition

if my id is in 1 then it should check id 4,5,6,7  or it should check value which is in id
this id i will pass as parameter to query

```
select * from table_a  where id
```

Help me in this

Comment: Your question is not clear? Can you add some more details as to what is the value, your table schema, sample data and output?

Comment: select * from individual ip where ip.prs_nationality_id =case  when  :p_prs_nat in( 219) then it shud check (231,259,343)
                                                               else
                                                              :p_prs_nat
                                                              end  how to achieve this functionality

Comment: You cannot directly use IN while returning the result in the THEN clause of CASE expression. However, you could first check the condition itself using AND operator and return TRUE whenever it matches. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below

```
select * from individual ip 
 where ( 
    ( :p_prs_nat  = 219 and ip.prs_nationality_id in (231,259,343) ) 
     or (:p_prs_nat <> 219 and :p_prs_nat=ip.prs_nationality_id
   ))
```

Answer (score 0):

> where ip.prs_nationality_id =case when :p_prs_nat in( 219) then it shud check (231,259,343) else :p_prs_nat end how to achieve this functionality

You cannot directly use **IN** while returning the result in the **THEN** clause of **CASE** expression. However, you could first check the condition itself using **AND** operator and return **TRUE** whenever it matches.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (
  3    SELECT 1 ID, 'X' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 2 ID, 'A' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 3 ID ,'P' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 4 ID ,'Q' STR FROM DUAL
  7    )
  8  SELECT *
  9  FROM DATA
 10  WHERE (
 11    CASE
 12      WHEN ID  = 1
 13      AND str IN ('A','Y','Z')
 14      THEN 1
 15      WHEN ID <> 1
 16      THEN 1
 17    END ) =1
 18  /

        ID S
---------- -
         2 A
         3 P
         4 Q

SQL>
```

So, you did not get the row with ID = 1,since it did not match the condition **`AND str IN ('A','Y','Z')`**.

If it would match, it will return those matching rows too:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (
  3    SELECT 1 ID, 'X' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 2 ID, 'A' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5    SELECT 3 ID ,'P' STR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 4 ID ,'Q' STR FROM DUAL
  7    )
  8  SELECT *
  9  FROM DATA
 10  WHERE (
 11    CASE
 12      WHEN ID  = 1
 13      AND str IN ('X','Y','Z')
 14      THEN 1
 15      WHEN ID <> 1
 16      THEN 1
 17    END ) =1
 18  /

        ID S
---------- -
         1 X
         2 A
         3 P
         4 Q

SQL>
```